# Firebase Google Auth with redirect error on ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

I am trying to implement Google Sign-In in my `React` + `Firebase` app. When I use the `signInWithPopup()` approach, everything works smoothly. However, when I use the `signInWithRedirect()` - my preferred approach - the authentication still works, but I get these annoying errors in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
    at foundation-chrome-content.js:3

Error in event handler for extension.onRequest: TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeEventListener' of null
    at bindShortcuts (chrome-extension://nlipoenfbbikpbjkfpfillcgkoblgpmj/javascripts/content_script.js:1:9424)
    at chrome-extension://nlipoenfbbikpbjkfpfillcgkoblgpmj/javascripts/content_script.js:1:13864
```

Here's my code that handles authentication on my `App.js`:

```
componentDidMount() {
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => this.setState({ user }));
  firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then(result => {
    var user = result.user;
    this.setState({ user });
  }).catch(error => {
    if (error.code === 'auth/account-exists-with-different-credential') {
      alert('You have already signed up with a different auth provider for that email.');
    } else {
      console.error(error);
    }
  });
}

toggleSignIn = () => {
  if (this.state.user) {
    firebase.auth().signOut();
  } else {
    var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider);
  }
}
```

I would appreciate any insights and help on this.

Comment: The errors appear to be coming from a chrome extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/awesome-screenshot-screen/nlipoenfbbikpbjkfpfillcgkoblgpmj

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know the long if can be used to find the extension. You're right, both errors were caused by chrome extensions - disabling them solved the bugs.